# The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin(n)\cdot\sin(1/n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

was doing math and I came across this series

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin n\cdot\sin\left(\dfrac1n\right)$$

I managed to prove that this series is convergent, but I was wondering what value the series converges to $?$
I've put it on Scientific workplace and got a value of around $0.92 $ But I have no idea how to get there.

Comment: *How* did you prove that that series converges?

Comment: @GEdgar No.I made that post but people understood something else.They thought i was asking about the general term limit,but it obviously converges to 0.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos using dirichlet test:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests

Comment: @PeterForeman using complex numbers you can compute the sum(sinkx).Just take z=cos(x)+isin(x).The sum are just the powers of z added together.Take the imaginary part in both sides and then put x=1

Comment: While it is possible that this converges to a value with some nice closed expression in terms of well-known values, I would guess against that being true. Taking the sine of rational values is not something that arises naturally from geometric-based constructions, which is where those closed expressions generally come from. Practically all real numbers do not have any such closed expression (though we spend almost all of our attention on those incredibly rare exceptions).